# Uso de "None" y "del" para eliminar nodos de una lista enlazada y manejo de memoria

Tags: python, python-3.x, pilas, memoria

Quise hacer una clase pila similar a la de c++ en Python y no se si estoy manejando bien la memoria y el tipo de dato `None` y quisiera que me explique el método `Ext()` de la clase `Pila`:

```
class Nodo( ):
    def __init__( self, val ):
        self.val = val
        self.sig = None
    def Dar_sig( self, sig ):
        self.sig = sig
    def Ret_val( self ):
        return self.val
    def Ret_sig( self ):
        return self.sig

class Pila( ):
    def __init__( self ):
        self.cim = None
    def Ins( self, val ):
        aux = Nodo( val )
        if self.cim != None:
            aux.Dar_sig( self.cim )
            self.cim = aux
        else:
            self.cim = aux
    def Ext( self ):
        if self.cim != None:
            aux = self.cim
            self.cim = self.cim.Ret_sig( )
            del aux
        else:
            print( "Pila vacia" )
    def Mos( self ):
        aux = self.cim
        while aux != None:
            print( aux.Ret_val( ) )
            aux = aux.Ret_sig( )

n = Pila( )
n.Ins( 4 )
n.Ins( 2 )
n.Ins( 5 )
n.Ins( 7 )
n.Mos( )
print( " -------- " )
n.Ext( )
n.Mos( )
print( " -------- " )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## ¿Qué es `None`?

En Python todo es un objeto que deriva de `object`, por lo tanto, para empezar `None` es un objeto.

El objeto `None` un objeto único de la clase/tipo `NoneType` cuyo único valor posible es `None`

Es un singleton, es decir, **solo existe una instancia de `NoneType` en un intérprete**, siempre, está asegurado como característica del lenguaje en CPython. Comparte ésta característica con los dos objetos de la clase `bool`, `True` y `False`.

**No se deben usar los operadores de igualdad o desigualdad para saber si algo es o no `None`**, como es un sigleton, **se debe usar el operador de identidad `is`**, cualquier valor `None` en el intérprete es el mismo objeto, es más legible y eficiente usar `is`/`is not` que `==`/`!=`.

`None` es un objeto que se usa para indicar 'vacío' o 'sin valor'. Significa eso porque la documentación de Python así lo indica, porque es un objeto igual que otro (con la particularidad de ser un sigleton). Es por tanto simplemente un objeto señal. Como es un valor, no debe interpretarse como `NULL` en C++, que para empezar solo se aplica a punteros.

Puede servir para declarar una variable que inicialmente no va a tener un valor real "definido".  En Python no hay que declarar una variable hasta que no tenga que ser usada, pero no pude haber variables "libres". Una variable es solo una etiqueta, un nombre **asociado siempre a un objeto en memoria**, si necesitamos declarar una variable y diferenciarla del caso del valor considerado vacío o cero para su "tipo", podemos usar `None`. No es lo mismo `lista = []` que `lista = None` y hay casos en los que ésta distinción es útil.

## ¿Qué hace `del`?

Recordemos lo que dijimos antes de las variables, son nombres asociados a un objeto en memoria, ni más ni menos. Una variable no tiene tipo, el tipo (clase) es propio del objeto. Por tanto una variable puede asociarse a otro objeto en cuanto queramos. Un objeto además puede tener las variables que queramos asociadas a él.

Python tiene un recolector de basura, dicho recolector tiene dos componentes:

- **Recolector por contador de referencias**: es extremadamente eficiente, simple y seguro. La idea es llevar la cuenta de las referencias que hay a todo objeto creado en memoria, en el momento que llega a cero (no hay ninguna referencia al objeto) el GC procede a destruirlo y liberar la memoria que ocupaba.
- **Recolector generacional**: el sistema anterior tiene un problema no obstante, no es capaz de detectar las referencias cíclicas. Para ello existe éste segundo componente. A diferencia del primero, no es inmediata la eliminación, éste componente actúa haciendo pasadas, ciclos, cada x tiempo.

El manejo de memoria da para otra pregunta o más, hay muchos más matices, por ejemplo, el intérprete suele mantener algunos objetos pequeños y comúnmente usados en memoria a pesar de no tener referencias, ésto lo hace por eficiencia. Son objetos que ocupan poco, son inmutables y estadísticamente muy usados, por lo que es mejor mantenerlos en memoria por si se usan después que no crearlos constantemente, no obstante ésto no es algo que asegure el lenguaje, son detalles de implementación y despenen de muchos factores (solo podemos asumir la existencia de `None`, `False` y `True`.).

Bien, lo que nos interesa es que **el manejo de memoria en Python es automático**, no es algo de lo que nos debamos ni realmente podemos ocuparnos a no ser que estemos implementando un extensión con la C-API en C. Es el recolector de basura el que decide cómo y cuando se elimina un objeto, que por norma general será cuando no tenga referencias o éstas sean cíclicas. El segundo componente del GC puede ser controlado, podemos detenerlo, forzar un ciclo de recolecta, especificar la frecuencia de recolecta, etc, pero el recolector por contador de referencias no. Permitir que el usuario elimine objetos a su antojo es permitir que se dispare en el pie si ya tenemos un GC, es precisamente uno de los problemas en lenguajes como C y C++ que otros como Rust tratan de paliar, si se elimina un objeto cuando aún hay referencias válidas a él, otra parte del código puede intentar acceder al objeto cuando ha sido eliminado sin saberlo, el resultado es...

Entonces ¿qué pinta `del` aquí? Bien, **`del` no elimina un objeto de memoria ni llama a su destructor, no directamente y no debemos asumir ésto jamás**. Un ejemplo muy simple:

```
class Test:
    def __del__(self):
        print("He sido destruido...")
```

> ```
> >>> foo = Test()
> >>> bar = foo
> >>> del foo # ¿No pasa nada?
> >>> bar = "Hola"
> He sido destruido... # ¿qué?
> ```

curioso ¿verdad?. `del foo` no parece haber hecho nada, pero si ha hecho, lo que hace `del` es eliminar referencias, variables o items de un contenedor, no el objeto asociado a ella. Analicemos paso a paso:

- **`foo = Test()`**:

  1. Creamos un objeto de la clase `Test`.
  2. Creamos una variable llamada `foo`.
  3. Se le asigna a `foo` una referencia al objeto de la clase recién creado.

  ---

  El contador de referencias para el objeto es en éste punto 1:
- **`bar = foo`**:

  1. Creamos una variable `bar`
  2. Le asignamos a `bar` otra referencia al mismo objeto al que está asociada `foo`. No se copia el objeto, solo se crea una nueva referencia la mismo.

  ---

  El contador de referencias del objeto en éste punto es 2.
- **`del foo`**:

  1. Se elimina la varible `foo`
  2. Se elimina por tanto la referencia al objeto a la que estaba asociada

  ---

  En éste punto el contador de referencias del objeto es 1 de nuevo.
- **`bar = "Hola"`**:

  1. Se crea un nuevo objeto `str`.
  2. Se asocia una referencia al objeto `str` a la variable bar.
  3. Se elimina la antigua referencia al objeto de la clase `Test`.

  ---

  En éste punto el contador de referencias del objeto `Test` es 0. El recolector de basura entra inmediatamente en acción y se elimina.

Por lo tanto, **llamar a `del` no implica que el objeto sea eliminado inmediatamente**, lo será solo si la variable o contenedor a la que se aplica `del` es la única referencia al objeto. Cosas que incrementan el contador de variables son, entre otras:

- Operador de asignación
- Paso de argumentos a funciones/métodos (Python pasa argumentos por asignación)
- Agregar el objeto a un contenedor (listas, diccionarios, conjuntos, etc)

---

El método de la clase Pila, con lo comentado:

- `if self.cim != None:` debe ser `if self.cim is not None:`.
- `aux = self.cim` incrementa en uno el contador de referencias del objeto `Nodo` asociado al atributo de instancia `self.cim`.
- `self.cim = self.cim.Ret_sig( )` decrementa en uno el contador de referencias al objeto `Nodo` anterior e incrementa en uno al retornado por `self.cim.Ret_sig`.
- `del aux` decrementa el contador de referencias del nodo inicial en uno. Será eliminado por el GC solo si dicho objeto `Nodo` no tiene otras referencias. Si tiene referencias pero son cíclicas será eliminado en algún momento cuando el GC haga una pasada de recolección.

La pregunta es ¿para qué hemos usado aux? Para nada, el contador de referencias del objeto ya se decrementa con `self.cim = self.cim.Ret_sig( )` y se eliminará si el GC considera que debe eliminarse.

---

Una implementación más "pitónica" sería por ejemplo:

```
class Nodo:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.valor = val
        self.siguiente = None

class Pila:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cima = None

    def insertar(self, valor):
        nodo = Nodo(valor)
        if self.cima is not None:
            nodo.siguiente = self.cima
        self.cima = nodo

    def extraer(self):
        if self.cima is not None:
            self.cima = self.cima.siguiente
        else:
            return None  # O lanzar una excepción

    def __iter__(self):
        self._actual = self.cima
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self._actual is not None:
            valor = self._actual.valor
            self._actual= self._actual.siguiente
            return valor
        else:
            raise StopIteration

    def __str__(self):
        return "\n".join(str(nodo) for nodo in self)


pila = Pila()
pila.insertar(4)
pila.insertar(2)
pila.insertar(5)
pila.insertar(7)
print(pila)
print(" -------- ")
pila.extraer()
print(pila)
print(" -------- ")
```

Python promueve el acceso directo a atributos, si se necesita ejecutar cierta lógica en un setter o getter se usan propiedades (properties) no métodos que actúen de getters o setters para mantener siempre el principio de acceso uniforme.

El resto son correcciones para cumplir con las convenciones e estilo para código Python y la implementación del protocolo iterador y del método `__str__` usado por `print` y por `str()`.

---

Preguntas relacionadas:

- [¿Cómo puedo forzar a una limpieza de memoria?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/272050/15089)
- [Funcionamiento del operador is](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/343143/15089)
- [¿Cómo crear un List de setters y getters en python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/100845/15089)
- [¿Cómo se aplica la encapsulación?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/361399/15089)